# Import .sql file with DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

Im trying to import a pretty big .sql file with data grip. It's called file.sql and I need it in the schemas section. But it only allows me to upload it under a schema file. Will it still work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it'll be fine.

Also, there're several ways to run "big" files:

1. Attach a file to project and execute `Run`

[image: run from attached file]

2. Run from Database Tool window via `Run SQL Script` or use `mysql`

[image: run from database tree]